# I have a ruby view that has this namespace: ActionView::Base.new but i want to add a new method to be available to this ActionView::Base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I have a ruby view that has this namespace: ActionView::Base.new but i want to add a new method to be available to this ActionView::Base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in myapp/lib/action_view_monkey_patch.rb do:

```
ActionView::Base.class_eval do
  def method_name
    #do some stuff
  end
end
```